# Difference between uniformly distributed variables, Python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, uniform-distribution

I'm very new to Python, and I was trying to use this problem as a learning exercise, but I can't get anywhere with it.

What I want to do is to show that for two random variables that come uniformly distributed within a 200ns window, the probability of them arriving within 7ns of each other is ~5%:

X, Y ~ U[0, 200]

Z = X - Y

P(|Z| < 7) = ?

I wanted to know the most analytical way of doing this, because I thought Python might have some useful libraries to help, and because if I wanted to do a stochastic simulation I would do it in C++ ROOT which would take me far less time!

The way that I've done it is below, but it's different from what I've calculated analytically. Can anyone suggest a better/more accurate way of solving the same problem?

Thanks a lot!

```
from scipy.stats import uniform, expon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

a, b = 0, 200
size = 1000000

# Genrating uniform distribution
uniform_distribution = uniform(loc=a, scale=b)
x = uniform_distribution.rvs(size=size)
y = uniform_distribution.rvs(size=size)

z=x-y

ax.hist(z)

zsmall=[z for i in z if abs(i)<7]

n=len(zsmall)

print("probability = ",n/size)
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Good work so far, you seem to be on the right track. It will help others help you if you say exactly what result you got, and exactly what you expected to get.

Comment: I've changed Z to |Z| in your equation above (line 7), to make the equation consistent with your explanation and code.

Comment: I agree with Robert, your code looks solid. You could save some memory by lining up smaller objects than the whole `z` for counting them, e.g. `zsmall=['' for i in z if abs(i)<7]`. Or the more readable `n = sum(abs(z) < 7)`, although that is significantly slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit: added some code to improve the figure.*

---

Your code is fine, and the results do agree with the analytically derived value. To see this more readily, I have modified your code slightly, scaling the domains of X and Y down to [0, 1] and computing P(|Z| < 7/200), so that this is still equivalent to your original question.

```py
from scipy.stats import uniform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a, b = 0, 1
size = 1000000

# generate uniformly distributed x and y
uniform_distribution = uniform(loc=a, scale=b)
x = uniform_distribution.rvs(size=size)
y = uniform_distribution.rvs(size=size)

z = x - y

# set up figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = [16, 8])
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlim([-1, 1])
ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
ax.set_xticks([-1, 0, 1])
ax.set_xticklabels([-1, 0, 1], size=20)
ax.set_yticks([0, 1])
ax.set_yticklabels([0, 1], size=20)

# plot histogram with y-axis scaled to show density, 
# increased bin number for better resolution
ax.hist(z, density=True, bins=200, alpha=0.5) 

# plot lines around the area we want to estimate
plt.axvline(-7/200, color='black', linestyle='--')
ax.annotate('x = -7/200', xy=(-7/200, 0.4), xytext=(-0.05, 0.4), fontsize=16, ha='right') 
plt.axvline( 7/200, color='black', linestyle='--')
ax.annotate('x = 7/200', xy=(7/200, 0.2), xytext=(0.05, 0.2), fontsize=16) 

# plot theoretical probability density function
ax.plot([-1, 0], [0, 1], color='gray', linestyle=':')
ax.plot([ 0, 1], [1, 0], color='gray', linestyle=':')

zsmall = [1 for i in z if abs(i) < 7/200]
n = len(zsmall)

print("probability =", n/size)
```

probability = **0.06857**

[image]

As you can see, this approaches the theoretically expected triangular distribution (gray dotted lines) pretty closely already. For comparison, we can calculate the theoretical probability, which is the area between the dashed lines and below the dotted lines. We can compute this as the area of the whole rectangle between the dashed lines minus the area of the square consisting of the two small triangles above the dotted lines:

```
2*(7/200) - (7/200)**2
```

= **0.068775**

So the theoretical value does agree with your simulation result.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! Turns out an MSci in physics isn't enough to stop one from making stupid mathematical slips!
In case anyone in future is interested: I did the integral differently - I said that the area that I'm interested in = 1-2*(the two external triangles)=1-2*0.5*(1-7/200)*(1-7/200)=1-(1-7/200)^2=0.068775.